# How To install Heroku in Fedora 25

Tags: python, heroku, fedora-25

I an Trying To install Heroku On my Fedora 25 For My Django Project  Machine but When i Put this in Terminal

> wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/heroku-REPLACE_ME_OS-REPLACE_ME_ARCH.tar.gz -O heroku.tar.gz

This Error Show

> --2017-04-12 14:13:47--  https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/heroku-REPLACE_ME_OS-REPLACE_ME_ARCH.tar.gz
>   Resolving cli-assets.heroku.com (cli-assets.heroku.com)... 54.230.190.177, 54.230.190.134, 54.230.190.243, ...
>   Connecting to cli-assets.heroku.com (cli-assets.heroku.com)|54.230.190.177|:443... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
>   2017-04-12 14:13:48 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Please Tell me instruction Step by Step

Answer (score 5):

An easier installation process has since been put together by the Heroku team:

```
curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

Taken from [this ticket](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/369).

Answer (score 1):

In `wget https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/heroku-REPLACE_ME_OS-REPLACE_ME_ARCH.tar.gz -O heroku.tar.gz` you must replace `REPLACE_ME_OS` and `REPLACE_ME_ARCH` with expected values.

From [heroku doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#standalone):

> Where REPLACE_ME_OS is one of “linux”, “darwin”, “windows”, “freebsd”, “openbsd” and REPLACE_ME_ARCH is one of “amd64”, “386” or “arm”